# Sorting an Array of comma separated string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split, array-map

I came across with a weird requirement and I am struggling for last few hours to complete it. Below is my Array of string(just an example, the actual array contains around 2500 records):

```
var testArray = [
  "130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489", 
  "129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078", 
  "138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"
]
```

We have 3 element here of which each element is `comma` separated(each element have 6 item). i.e:

```
testArray[0] = "130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489"
```

My problem is, I wanted to sort `testArray` based on the first item of each element and convert it to array of array having all value into float, so the output would be:

```
[
  [129, 875, 875, 828.1, 833.25, 6926078],
  [130, 839.9, 855, 837.3, 848.65, 3980489],
  [138, 891.3, 893.3, 865.2, 868.75, 5035618]
]
```

I am able to sort individual item but not the entire array as a whole, and I have tried using split and then sort with no luck.

Can someone help me out with this and please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: It's always better to show the attempts aswell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the array using [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) within an [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then use [**`Array#sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the converted array according to the `[0]` indices (`a[0] - b[0]`):

### In ES5

```js
var testArray = [
  "130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489", 
  "129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078", 
  "138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"
]

var converted = testArray.map(function (item) {
  return item.split(',').map(function (num) {
    return parseFloat(num);
  });
})
console.log(converted)

var sorted = converted.sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0] })
console.log(sorted)
```

### In ES6

```js
const testArray = [
  "130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489", 
  "129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078", 
  "138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"
]

const converted = testArray.map(
  item => item.split(',').map(
    num => parseFloat(num)
  )
)
console.log(converted)

const sorted = converted.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
console.log(sorted)
```

### In ES6 (condensed)

```js
const testArray = [
  "130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489", 
  "129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078", 
  "138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"
]

const convertedAndSorted = testArray
  .map(n => n.split(',')
  .map(num => parseFloat(num)))
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

console.log(convertedAndSorted)
```

Comment: There's a typo in ES5 code: `return item.split('.')` should be `return item.split(',')`.

Answer (score 1):

First convert each of the Strings to an array of floats values using `Array.map()` and `parseFloat()`.
After that you can simply sort the array of arrays using `Arrays.sort()`

Try the following :

```js
var arr = ["130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489","129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078","138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"];

var result = arr.map((a)=> a.split(",").map((b)=>parseFloat(b))).sort((a,b)=> a[0] -b[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are sorting floats as strings.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for pointing it out, i made i typo when i edited the question.

Comment: Btw, before the edit, your sort even first coerced the sub-arrays to strings and then sorted them as strings, which was just a bit too harsh.

Answer (score 1):

Just map the splitted and to number formatted values and sort by the first item.

```js
var data = ["130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489", "129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078", "138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"],
    result = data
        .map(s => s.split(',').map(Number))
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var testArray = ["130,839.9,855,837.3,848.65,3980489","129,875,875,828.1,833.25,6926078","138,891.3,893.3,865.2,868.75,5035618"];

const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    var numbers = testArray[i].split(',');
    for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        numbers[j] = +numbers[j];
    }
    output[i] = numbers;
}
output.sort(function(x, y) {
    return x[0] - y[0];
});
```

or shorter

```
output = testArray.map(s => s.split(',')).map(e => e.map(n => +n)).sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0]);
```